# "Shouldn't you be at work?"

Tags: grammar, phrases, questions

Say you should be at work.  Would the correct answer be "yes" or "no"? The common answer would be "yes", but isn't that really saying, "yes, I should not be at work"?

Comment: You are taking it a bit too literally. The question is rhetorical. "Shouldn't you be at work?" is another way of saying "You should be at work, right?" the answer to which would be "Yeah, I should" which is the same answer to the original rhetorical question.

Comment: @Ghaith Alrestom The answer to a rhetorical question is . But JDP _is_ overthinking this, expecting idiomatic English to be logical.

Comment: Well, would "Don't you have class?" be rhetorical?  When I was in high school and on my free period, some kids would be ask me that and I would always respond, obviously with a "no".  But the question _technically_ means "Do you not have class?"

Comment: Usually, in these cases, people will regularly clarify their answer by continuing the sentence... "Yes, I should" or "No, I shouldn't". They may even explain why they are or are not supposed to be.